# PWA works on "/index.html" but not "/"

Tags: angular, nginx, progressive-web-apps

I created an Angular PWA and it works if you visit `https://domain.tld/index.html`. The `index.html` is also removed from the URL since `"/"` is equivalent to the `index`.

With that said if you refresh the page offline it no longer works as expected. The url changes to `https://domain.tld/`. If you are offline and visit `https://domain.tld/index.html` it works and it's served from the cache. So it only works if you access `/index.html` if you visit `"/"` it throws a `504`.

I don't know how to solve this issue.

`ngsw-config.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "daily-api",
      "urls": ["https://api-link.net/daily.json"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 10,
        "maxAge": "3d12h",
        "timeout": "3s"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought the issue might be the `"index"` property but I don't understand why `"/" != "/index.html"` for the offline PWA.

I'm using nginx to serve the content so maybe that is the issue?

```
....

index         index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

...
```

My angular routes consist of:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./rooms/rooms.module').then(m => m.RoomsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'rooms',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

I'm at a loss for trying to solve this. I can't seem to find any resources with why offline works on `index.html` but not on `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a server where I tried to deploy an Angular app with PWA. I was able to fix it by modifying the `ngsw-worker.js` file, adding a condition immediately at the beginning of the `onFetch` function:

```js
onFetch(event) {
    if (event.request.url === 'https://[[your-app-host]].com/') {
        return event.respondWith(fetch(`${event.request.url}index.html`));
    }
    // ...
}
```

To automate, run a script called `fix-sw.js`, in the root folder of the project, which reads the published service worker and modifies it

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const outputPath = './dist/';
const swPath = `${outputPath}/ngsw-worker.js`;
const input = fs.readFileSync(swPath, 'utf8');
const fix = "if (event.request.url === 'https://[[your-app-host]].com/') { return event.respondWith(fetch(`${event.request.url}index.html`)); }";
const output = input.replace(/(\bonFetch\(\w+\)\s*{)/, `$1 ${fix}`);
fs.writeFileSync(swPath, output, 'utf8');
```

and then add it to the package.json script:

```json
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "build": "ng build && node fix-sw.js",
    // ...
}
```

I hope you find it useful!